# I need to raise an exception if the report comes in blank or with zero data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to raise but as I am new to ruby on rails I am so lost on what to make an exception if the report comes empty. Below is the code of the service:

```
class ReportService
  def self.generate_report(params, type, data_type = 'data')
    "#{type}Report".constantize.send("report_#{data_type}", params)
  end

  def Not_Blank
    raise Exception.new('Deu ruim!') unless @data_type.blank?
  end
end
```

The controller looked like this:

```
class Backend::ReportUsersController < Backend::Controller
  respond_to :html, :xlsx, :pdf
  load_and_authorize_resource :user, :parent => false
  before_action :check_permissions

  def report
    if params[:user_report][:institutes].reject!(&:blank?).blank?
      return redirect_to(
        report_users_path,
        alert: I18n.t('report.user.error.institute_required')
      )
    end

    if params[:user_report][:start_at].blank?
      params[:user_report][:start_at] = I18n.l(User.first.created_at.to_date, format: :default)
    end

    if params[:user_report][:end_at].blank?
      params[:user_report][:end_at] = I18n.l(Date.current, format: :default)
    end

    params[:user_report][:current_user] = current_user.name
    if params [:user_report][:total_participants].blank?
      return redirect_to(
        report_users_path,
        alert: I18n.t('report.user.error.cannot_generate_blank_or_empty_report')
      )
    end
    @report = ReportService.generate_report(params[:user_report], 'User')
    @pagy, @report_data = pagy_array(JSON[@report[:data]], size: [2,2,2,2])

  end

  def generate_file
    if params[:format] == 'pdf'
      institutes = Institute.where(id: params[:report][:institute_ids])

      if institutes.size == 1
        @logo = institutes[0].logo
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf do
          render pdf: I18n.t('activerecord.models.user.other'),
          margin: { top: 30 },
          footer: {
            font_size: 10,
            left: "#{I18n.t('report.research.general_labels.generated_at')}: " +
              "#{I18n.l(DateTime.current, format: :default_without_seconds)} | " +
              "#{I18n.t('report.research.general_labels.by')}: " +
              "#{@current_user.name}",
            right: "[page] #{I18n.t('report.research.general_labels.of')} [topage]"
          },
          orientation: 'Landscape',
          template: "backend/report_users/layout_pdf.html.erb"
        end
      end
    elsif params[:format] == 'xlsx'
      report = ReportService.generate_report(params, 'User', 'excel')

      respond_to do |format|
        format.xlsx { render xlsx: report[:file], filename: I18n.t('report.user.file_name.report_users') }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def check_permissions
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless @current_user.full_manager?
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow content must be in English.

Comment: @meagar OP translated the question, would you mind to reopen?

Comment: _"I tried to raise ..."_ – you put the code to raise the exception into an instance method `Not_Blank`, but that method is never called. Some questions arise: why is `Not_Blank` an instance method (as opposed to a class method like `generate_report`)? Why do you use uppercase letters in a method name – is that a custom naming convention in your project? Why did you put that line into its own method in the first place, i.e. why don't you raise right from within `generate_report`? Maybe it would help if you could explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: FYI, there's a Portuguese Stack Overflow: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: It seems like the `Not_Blank` method is backward - don't you want to raise the error `if @data_type.blank?` not `unless @data_type.blank?`

Comment: I managed to fix it. I had to treat the exception in another class. Thanks for the answers I'm still learning at RoR

Comment: Show us how you fixed it, it could help somebody who would have the same problem later on?

Comment: In user_report.rb I made an exception that looked like this:
'if data.detect{ |a| a[3]!=0 }.blank?
      raise Exceptions::ReportUserError,
        I18n.t('report.user.errors.cannot_generate_blank_or_empty_report')
    end '

In the controller I did the rescue:

'rescue Exceptions::ReportUserError'
 
And I created the exceptions.rb in the lib folder. The only mistake that came up was: "uninitialized constant UserReport::Exceptions"